# Solana web3 js failed to get recent blockhash error 403

Tags: web3js, solana

I am trying to implement sendtransaction for phantom In my application.

here's my code:

```
sendTransaction(amount, depositWallet) { (async () => {
    try {
      const resp = await window.solana.connect();
      this.wallet = resp;
      this.signInTransactionAndSendMoney(amount, depositWallet);
      console.log(amount, depositWallet)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })();
},
signInTransactionAndSendMoney(amount, depositWallet) {
  (async () => {
    try {
      const network = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
      const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(network);
      const candidate = amount * solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
      const destPubkey = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(depositWallet);
      const instruction = solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: this.wallet.publicKey,
        toPubkey: destPubkey,
        lamports: candidate,
      });
      const trans = await this.setWalletTransaction(instruction, connection);
      const signature = await this.signAndSendTransaction(this.wallet, trans, connection);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })();
},
async setWalletTransaction(instruction, connection) {
  const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();
  transaction.add(instruction);
  transaction.feePayer = this.wallet.publicKey;
  const hash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  console.log(hash)
  transaction.recentBlockhash = hash.blockhash;
  return transaction;
},
async signAndSendTransaction(wallet, transaction, connection) {
  // Sign transaction, broadcast, and confirm
  const { signature } = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);
  await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
  return signature;
},
```

but when im trying to send the transaction I get an error

> Error: failed to get recent blockhash: Error: 403 :  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 403, "message":"Access forbidden, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com."}, "id": "001d039f-ad38-4942-a379-5db2f7951ebf" }

Comment: is there anything to do with buffer? i fixed it with import * as buffer from "buffer";
window.Buffer = buffer.Buffer;

Answer (score 0):

Changed to quicknode rpc url solved the problem.

Comment: Please could you expand on your answer to help others with more information on why this solved the problem, specifically why this rpc as well, and supply sources to the documentation or further information.